# Wordpress display breadcrumbs using Yoast plugin

Tags: plugins, posts, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, breadcrumb

Hi so for all my Wordpress 5.4 site’s posts (articles), I'm using Yoast SEO plugin for breadcrumbs across my site.

For all my posts (articles) I just want:

Home > CategoryLink > as breadcrumbs, not the topic of the post.

So I’ve tried the following code in my theme's functions.php:

```
 add_filter( ‘wpseo_breadcrumb_links’, ‘wpseo_breadcrumb_remove_postname’ );
```

function wpseo_breadcrumb_remove_postname( $links ) {

if( sizeof($links) > 1 ) {

array_pop($links);
}

return $links;

}

However, what the hack above does is it also removes the previous link (parent link) and publishes only text instead of a link.

So if I have links as follows:

Home> CategoryUrl > Title of Post

Applying the patch into functions.php results in this:

Home > CategoryText

So the Category name is not a link anymore but a text. So breadcrumbs are useless after this hack.

Is there a correct way of not displaying post title in the breadcrumbs using Yoast? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function remove_breadcrumb_title( $link_output) {
if(strpos( $link_output, 'breadcrumb_last' ) !== false ) {
    $link_output = '';
}
return $link_output;
```

}
add_filter('wpseo_breadcrumb_single_link', 'remove_breadcrumb_title' );

Answer (score 0):

I went to the Yoast website and just took a look at the breadcrumbs they use:

```
<nav class="row breadcrumb" aria-label="You are here:">
    <span>
        <span><a href="https://yoast.com/">Home</a> » 
            <span><a href="https://yoast.com/help/">Help center</a> » 
                <span><a href="https://yoast.com/help/category/wordpress-plugins/">WordPress plugins</a> » 
                    <span><a href="https://yoast.com/help/category/yoast-seo-woocommerce/">Yoast SEO: WooCommerce</a> » 
                        <span class="breadcrumb_last" aria-current="page">How to implement Yoast SEO breadcrumbs</span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</nav>
```

You'll notice that the last nested `<span>` tag has a class of `.breadcrumb_last`.

You could add the following to your style.css:

```
nav.row.breadcrumb .breadcrumb_last{
    display:none;
}
```

This may actually be advisable because the `aria-current` is still available for assistive technologies.

I should add that this operates on the assumption that the way your breadcrumbs are being output is the same HTML format, so you'll need to check that first, but if it is, this should address it.  You may also need to, and I'm loathe to say this, add an `!important` to your CSS rule in case Yoast's stylesheet executes after yours.  Try without it though and see what happens.

Comment: So I tried google search and found this code to functions.php that works:  <code>function remove_breadcrumb_title( $link_output) {
 if(strpos( $link_output, 'breadcrumb_last' ) !== false ) {
  $link_output = '';
 }
    return $link_output;
}
add_filter('wpseo_breadcrumb_single_link', 'remove_breadcrumb_title' );</code>

Comment: Apologies I don't know formatting of comments.

Comment: That’s exactly it.  I think by hiding it with CSS it’s a lot easier and makes a bit more sense than re-writing the entire output.

Comment: You think the css code will work too?

Comment: My answer is the CSS code, the HTML was just an example of what the breadcrumbs could look like.  The answer is the actual CSS I posted.

Comment: Ok I’ll try that too

Comment: Hi Tony so I checked my site's html code with breadcrumb and there is no "breadcrumb_last" class in it.

Comment: Are you using the function you posted in the comments as well as the CSS?

Comment: Hi so there is a <span class="breadcrumb_last" aria-current="page"> nothing else before that. No other class before.

Comment: Perfect.  So now just apply the CSS in my answer to your style sheet and that should hide it.

Comment: Ok it worked thanks.. I used .breadcrumb_last { visibility: hidden; display: none; }

Comment: But I can see the separator too :-( It's the slash /

Comment: The separators are part of the preceding link.